# Unresolved import 'pubsub'

Tags: python, blockchain, publish-subscribe, distributedpubsub

I am working with Python, JS, & React, and I am following the "Build a Blockchain & Cryptocurrency" Course

Half way into the course, unable to resolve this problem when setting up Real-Time Messaging through PubSub (if you are Python blockchain developer, you may know what I mean (I am very new into blockchain programming).

Error:

[image: Error Img]

Installed PubSub:

[image: Installed pubsub]

Comment: are you sure you are using the same version as the guy in the course?

Comment: Re-installed the course version. Still getting the error

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: New to stackoverflow. Noted